# Does having a spoon in the cup keep your coffee hot for longer?

Tags: physics, coffee

I was recently told that having a metal spoon in the coffee would heat the cup of coffee up, and that it would be hotter if I stirred because of the conductivity of the metal in the spoon. This seems counter intuitive because wouldn't the spoon radiate the heat out from the handle?

He provided an answer I didn't quite understand (he's an engineer), but I have to check here.

Is this true?

Comment: Related (top voted) question on Physics.SE:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon

Comment: Is this type of question actually more appropriate for a technical site?  it's not so much about "proving/disproving a claim made somewhere [really, in the media]" as just "me and my buddy were discussing X technical issue".

Comment: @joe many people believe this claim. So, it is notable and on-topic here. It might get a *better* answer somewhere else, but it can still be asked here.

Comment: @dawn - fair enough, if it is a **"broadly believed claim"**, then you're quite right it's good on here.  Thanks for that

Comment: @Will Actually, that should count as a reference to make an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spoon's conductivity would only heat the coffee if you were holding the spoon with a super-hot hand. Assuming the spoon (and your hand) are both cooler than the coffee, they will both conduct heat away from the liquid, causing the coffee to cool a teensy bit more quickly.

Stirring the liquid should logically only speed the process.

Believe it or not, a fellow nerd on physics.stackexchange.com conducted an experiment on this very issue and published the results, which confirm my hypothesis:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon

Comment: related: https://what-if.xkcd.com/71/